# how can i implement shadcn table react but instead of using GlobalFilter or ColumnFilter i want to make a custom function with fulltext search prisma

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, tanstack

### how can i implement shadcn table with react but instead of using GlobalFilter or ColumnFilter i want to make a custom function with fulltext search of prisma

i have idea now on implementing prisma with fullsearch im reading their docs.

in react tanstack table i search and watch some tutorial but i got no luck im referring tanstack docs on how can i implement that. i have an idea but i dont know how can i make that. im just seeking help for any referrence so i can make it with a less of time

i used chatgpt but i think theres no better explanation. i watch some tutorials about implementing of shadcn table and test unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did you initiate the TanStack Table? Have you read on the table options? I'd pay particular attention to `data`.

> When the data option changes reference (compared via Object.is), the table will reprocess the data.

Reference: https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/table#options

Comment: As data here is just an input, and as the doc suggested,  a change in the data will result to the table being re-rendered. You can have a function that listens to your `globalFilter`, do the search, and save the results to data (hint: useQuery)

Reference: 

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery

Comment: thanks for your response @aldnav im able to fix this now instead of using globalfilter i switch to use openAI semantic search so we can sort for more relevant context of what i search and im able to rerendered the data result